# Helper class to achieve common task

Tags: c#, asp.net, helper

I would like to create a helper class to do some common task.

For example, I am retrieving some results from Database and then assigning the values to variables. But some of the fields in my records might contain null as well. I would like to check before assigning that the value does not contain any null.

Also there are some variable those are type int, so like to check before parsing to the specific type.

```
int iValue=int.parse(Helpers.IsNull(dr[colName].toString()));
string strValue=Helpers.IsNull(dr[colName].toString());
```

How should I create a helper class and what value should I return with IsNull method?

Little confuse..

Thanks

Comment: is dr ==  DataReader?

Comment: [Helper](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nickmalik/archive/2005/09/06/461404.aspx) [Classes](http://lostechies.com/chrismissal/2009/05/26/anti-patterns-and-worst-practices-you-re-doing-it-wrong/) [is an](http://scottboring.com/the-helper-anti-pattern/) [anti-pattern](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/134540/are-utility-classes-with-nothing-but-static-members-an-anti-pattern-in-c)

Comment: Is there any solution??

Answer (score 1):

Well what you are trying to acchieve is to avoid the NullReferenceException i guess.

You could achieve this by writing a generic method like this

```
public static TValue GetValueSafe<TValue,TObject>(TObject obj, Func<TObject,TValue> accessor)
{
    if(obj== null)
        return default(TValue);

    return accessor(obj);
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
string strValue = Helpers.GetValueSafe(dr[colName], o => o.toString());
```

This would either return the value of toString, or if dr[colName] == null returns default(string) which is null.

You could exand this by adding a defaultParameter to define a value on "failure".

However i would'nt recommend using this.

Comment: IF you don't recommend, then whats the best solution?

Comment: Look at the comments from your question.

Answer (score 1):

A more radical approach (which would remove the issue) would be to eradicate NULLs from your values altogether.

The simplest way would be through `ISNULL()` when you query your database:

Where now you do

```
SELECT MyColumn FROM MyTable
```

You instead go

```
SELECT ISNULL(MyColumn, '') AS MyColumn FROM MyTable
```

Then you can assume no NULLs will get through to your code.