# Why are helperclasses anti pattern

Tags: oop, design-patterns

A recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22025340/helper-class-to-achieve-common-task/) here made me rethink this whole helper classes are anti pattern thing.

asawyer pointed out a few links in the comments to that question:
[Helper](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nickmalik/archive/2005/09/06/461404.aspx) [classes](http://lostechies.com/chrismissal/2009/05/26/anti-patterns-and-worst-practices-you-re-doing-it-wrong/) [is an](http://scottboring.com/the-helper-anti-pattern/) [anti-pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134540/are-utility-classes-with-nothing-but-static-members-an-anti-pattern-in-c).

While those links go into detail how helperclasses collide with the well known principles of oop some things are still unclear to me.

For example "Do not repeat yourself". How can you acchieve this without creating some sort of helper?
I thought you could derive a certain type and provide some features for it. 
But I bellieve that isnt practical all the time.

Lets take a look at the following example,
please keep in mind I tried not to use any higher language features nor "languagespecific" stuff. So this might been ugly nested and not optimal...

```
//Check if the string is full of whitepsaces
bool allWhiteSpace = true;

if(input == null || input.Length == 0)
    allWhiteSpace  = false;
else 
{
    foreach(char c in input)
    {
        if( c != ' ')
        {
            allWhiteSpace = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Lets create a bad helper class called StringHelper, the code becomes shorter:

```
bool isAllWhiteSpace = StringHelper.IsAllWhiteSpace(input);
```

So since this isnt the only time we need to check this, i guess "Do not repeat yourself" is fullfilled here.

How do we acchieve this without a helper ? Considering that this piece of Code isn't bound to a single class?

Do we need to inherit string and call it BetterString ?

```
bool allWhiteSpace = better.IsAllWhiteSpace;
```

or do we create a class? StringChecker

```
StringChecker checker = new StringChecker();

bool allWhiteSpace = checker.IsAllwhiteSpace(input);
```

So how do we acchieve this?

Some languages (e.g. C#) allow the use of ExtensionMethods. Do they count as helperclasses aswell? I tend to prefer those over helperclasses.

Comment: I disagree that helper classes are an anti-pattern. I find that *static* classes are an avoidable-pattern. As such, I use dependency injection *and* helper classes - in C#. (In my experience, such use of DI and helper classes make it easier to unify and test small bits of helper - that is, "pure function" - code.)

Comment: Extension methods in C# and similarly implicit conversion in Scala are *not* related to "hyperclasses" or types, excluding that they are used to resolve the *static compile-time binding*. Any extension methods `o.Ext(g)` in C# can be written as `M.Ext(o, g)`.

Comment: Since you're question is language agnostic, and the example is trying to add functionality to some (presumable) native string type, Why not place it in a function instead of a static class member?

Comment: I think [this answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/134543/117325) from one of those links best answers your question. `StringHelper` is a namespace, not a class, and there's nothing wrong with it. The only problem is, in *some* languages, it *must* be a class.

Comment: Having the functionality as a class method may make testing/mocking it impossible.  So having it injected instead of fixed static calls is prefered.  If this is true for some simple string helpers leaves room for argueing.

Comment: @cfrick Only if the functions use global state.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Disclaimer: the following answer is based on my own experience and I'm not making a point of right and wrong.

IMHO, Helper classes are neither good nor bad, it all depends on your business/domain logic and your software architecture.
Here's Why:
lets say that we need to implement the idea of white spaces you proposed, so first I will ask my self.
When would I need to check against white spaces?
Hence, imagine the following scenario: a blogging system with Users, Posts, Comments. Thus, I would have three Classes:

```
Class User{}
Class Post{}
Class Comment{}
```

each class would have some field that is a string type. Anyway, I would need to validate these fields so I would create something like:

```
Class UserValidator{}
Class PostValidator{}
Class CommentValidator{}
```

and I would place my validation policies in those three classes. But **WAIT!** all of the aforementioned classes needs a check against null or all whitespaces? Ummmm....
the best solution is to take it higher in the tree and put it in some **Father** class called Validator:

```
Class Validator{
   //some code
   bool function is_all_whitespaces(){}
}
```

so, if you need the function `is_all_whitespaces(){}` to be abstract ( with class validator being abstract too) or turn it into an interface that would be another issue and it depends on your way of thinking mostly.
back to the point in this case I would have my classes ( for the sake of giving an example ) look like:

```
Class UserValidator inherits Validator{}
Class PostValidator inherits Validator{}
Class CommentValidator inherits Validator{}
```

in this case I really don't need the helper at all. but lets say that you have a function called `multiD_array_group_by_key`
and you are using it in different positions, but you don't like to have it in some OOP structured place you can have in some `ArrayHelper` but by that you are a step behind from being fully object oriented.

Comment: Well I guess you have to keep that in mind at the start of the coding process, if u try to implemnt any of it later down the road you'll get frustrated fast.

Comment: @CSharpie - yes, even though you should keep your code [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) so you don't get frustrated. and this is why software design is important, as for those things to be kept in mind at the very beginning of code implementation

Answer (score 17):

Helper classes may be bad (there are always exceptions) because a well-designed OO system will have clearly understood responsibilities for each class. For example, a `List` is responsible for managing an ordered list of items. Some people new to OOD who discover that a class has methods to do stuff with its data sometimes ask "why doesn't `List` have a `dispayOnGUI` method (or similar such thing)?". The answer is that it is not the responsibility of `List` to be concerned with the GUI.

If you call a class a "Helper" it really doesn't say anything about what that class is supposed to do.

A typical scenario is that there will be some class and someone decides it is getting too big and carves it up into two smaller classes, one of which is a helper. It often isn't really clear what methods should go in the helper and what methods should stay in the original class: the responsibility of the helper is not defined.

It is hard to explain unless you are experienced with OOD, but let me show by an analogy. By the way, I find this analogy extremely powerful:

Imagine you have a large team in which there are members with different job designations: e.g, front-end developers, back-end developers, testers, analysts, project managers, support engineers, integration specialists, etc. (as you like).

Each role you can think of as a class: it has certain responsibilities and the people fulfilling those responsibilities hopefully have the necessary knowledge to execute them. These roles will interact in a similar way to classes interacting.

Now imagine it is discovered that the back-end developers find their job too complicated. You can hire more if it is simply a throughput problem, but perhaps the problem is that the task requires too much knowledge across too many domains. It is decided to split up the back-end developer role by creating a new role, and maybe hire new people to fill it.

How helpful would it be if that new job description was "Back-end developer helper"? Not very ... the applicants are likely to be given a haphazard set of tasks, they may get confused about what they are supposed to do, their co-workers may not understand what they are supposed to do.

More seriously, the knowledge of the helpers may have to be exactly the same as the original developers as we haven't really narrowed down the actual responsibilities.

So "Helper" isn't really saying anything in terms of defining what the responsibilities of the new role are. Instead, it would be better to split-off, for example, the database part of the role, so "Back-end developer" is split into "Back-end developer" and "Database layer developer".

Calling a class a helper has the same problem and the solution is the same solution. You should think more about what the responsibilities of the new class should be. Ideally, it should not just shave-off some methods, but should also take some data with it that it is responsible for managing and thereby create a solution that is genuinely simpler to understand piece by piece than the original large class, rather than simply placing the same complicated logic in two different places.

I have found in some cases that a helper class is well designed, but all it lacks is a good name. In this case, calling it "Builder" or "Formatter" or "Context" instead of "Helper" immediately makes the solution far easier to understand.

Comment: If you do not have access to the code, because you are using a third party library, i think what you wrote does not apply. Your last sentence probably says that. I agree on the naimg there. Thank you for this insight.

Comment: Yes - I see what you mean. To a certain extent, Java classes such as `Collections` and `Arrays` are valid examples of helpers (although they are not named as such) as are the Apache `Utils` classes as they extend the functionality of the standard classes. So as always, there are exceptions which dodge the anti-pattern. However, the `Swift` language lets you extend classes which to a certain extent invalidates that excuse for creating util/helpers.

Comment: Helpers are very useful for unit testing. When you have a certain non-trivial logic to be tested, it goes much MUCH easier when that logic consists of trivial operations ("Divide-and-Conquer" design strategy). They are implemented by helpers. In such case, each helper can be easily mocked, letting you focus on testing the logic. Helpers, in turn, can be easily tested in isolation. This makes your overall test coverage much better. But for the whole thing to work out, the helpers must be *instantiable* because otherwise the dependency injection cannot work. This brings us to helper classes.